# SwiftUI CoreData: Multiple entities in one PreviewProvider

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, swiftui

I have 2 entities, for each of these entities i created a persisctenceControllerPreview in my PersistenceController file. Like this:

```
    static var timerObjectPreview: PersistenceController = {
        let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
        let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
        for _ in 0..<10 {
            let previewTimerObject = TimerObject(context: viewContext)
            previewTimerObject.id = UUID()

            
        }
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
        return result
    }()
    
    static var stopWatchObjectPreview: PersistenceController = {
        let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
        let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
        for _ in 0..<10 {
            let previewStopwatchObject = StopWatchObject(context: viewContext)
            previewStopwatchObject.id = UUID()

        }
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
        return result
    }()
```

Now, I want to show both entites in one view, of course this view has a PreviewProvider. I know, i have to set the managedObjectContext environment of my PreviewProvider to:

```
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.timerObjectPreview.container.viewContext)
```

But this only works for one of my two PersistenceControllers.

```
        HomeView()
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.timerObjectPreview.container.viewContext)
```

or like this:

```
        HomeView()
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.stopWatchObjectPreview.container.viewContext)
```

So, what do I have to do now to show both entities in my preview?
PS: This doesn´t work:

```
        HomeView()
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.timerObjectPreview.container.viewContext)
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.stopWatchObjectPreview.container.viewContext)
```

Greetings!

Comment: I think your issue is simply that you are creating 2 separate `viewContexts`, one for each entity. Instead, create one context, and then place both entities into it.

Comment: I agree, all you have to do is to merge the two `for` loops into one.

Comment: You are welcome. I think the confusion with the different answers is that you did not provide your `HomeView()` so no one was sure how you were using the entities in the view (were they mutually exclusive, etc.). Also, you can't ever have two different values for the same `.environment` variable. It is like to identically named variables in the view itself, except in this case, the compiler didn't complain.

Answer (score 0):

One environment variable can have only one value, so for your case I would recommend just to have two previews, like

```
struct Demo_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeView()                       // << 1st preview
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.timerObjectPreview.container.viewContext)
        HomeView()                       // << 2nd preview
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.stopWatchObjectPreview.container.viewContext)    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the solution of @Yrb is the best for me